# Regex: Matching any URL except those containing ".js" and ".css"

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I am trying to replace every link of an HTML page so people can click on it.
But I can't find the Regex for the pattern:

**href="Any_URL"**    except those containing ".js" or ".css" ( in the middle or at the end of the URL)

I tried many patterns like  **href=".+(.css|.js){0}.*"**

The idea is to get the content of a website and replace every URL ( except those containing .js and .css) by href="#" so people can't click on it.

**$subject = file_get_contents($url, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);** // get the content of the website

**$pattern='#href=".+(.css|.js){0}.*"#i'** // doesn't work

**$page=preg_replace($pattern, 'href=#', $subject);** // replace all the links by something not clickable

**return $page;**

Comment: `{0}` means match zero times, it doesn't mean to ensure it's not there. You would instead need to use an assertion, like `\.(?!css|js)\w+`

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an XPath query, and then you have a simple substring search to do on the returned href attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

{0} only apply to matches. So it won't compute in the match, but could be there. 
Try this:

```
href="(.+)(?<!\.css|\.js)"
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uccHzD/2)

Comment: unfortunatly this regex doesn't work with URL like

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/11UGK4%2BGCNL._RC|11ikU6MX1JL.css,01ekIXTj5kL.css,21rTx+UpnSL.css,21GzlFOlcvL.css,01OT3mZ3tNL.css,11xRy3bSkOL.css,01TCV-xmeZL.css,01D-B-OeNDL.css,01FlII1u-ZL.css,2184gziDrML.css,01QUs5FVXoL.css,11MXghh1eBL.css,016ZWeUMVEL.css,41vOQb1k0LL.css,31MkQHV3gaL.css,01GT2VH57dL.css,314gb2LkLML.css,01xHpyZh3cL.css,01rgQ3jqo7L.css,21a4ZBDoZ2L.css,31e6R41SWLL.css,11X8K4AolpL.css,21PjfsP9YvL.css,31l-lBYTowL.css,014Z+MbaRaL.css,01RRH0yFa4L.css,31Fo-RK+JML.css,01ZGR4PDSTL.cs" />

Comment: When I say "doesn't work", I mean it matches this URL and replace it ( and it's not what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 0):

This should reject anything with `.css` or `.js` in it, using a negative lookahead:

`/href=".+\.(?!css|js).+"/`